Counting of white granules by their diameter
I'm trying to calculate number of white granules and their diameters in a given image (e.g. below).

import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image = cv2.imread(r'D:\Downloads\IMG_0009.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (11, 11), 0)
canny = cv2.Canny(blur, 10, 150)
dilated = cv2.dilate(canny, (1, 1), iterations=2)
(cnt, _) = cv2.findContours(dilated.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours(image, cnt, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow('Contours', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print('image:', len(cnt))

At the moment it more or less works, but maybe there are better and more accurate options
import cv2
import numpy as np


image = cv2.imread('D:\Downloads\IMG_0009.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blurred, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1.30, minDist=30,
                            param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=5, maxRadius=50)

if circles is not None:
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
    

    for (x, y, r) in circles:

        cv2.circle(image, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)

    cv2.imwrite('D:\Downloads\detected_circles.jpg', image)
    print("D:\Downloads\detected_circles.jpg")
else:
    print("Nothing")```


Hey @Дмитрий.  It's not clear what you're asking.  What about the code you have doesn't work / what speifically do you need help with?  Are you getting an error, an incorrect result, or you're not sure how to complete some step?  It looks like you're using the opencv (cv2) library to help; it may be worth adding some info on what you're expecting that library's functions to do for you.  If you can improve your question you're more likely to get a helpful answer.

This code calculates the number of granules, but I would like it to allocate them in an oval or a circle, depending on the selected diameter. I tried different methods, but for some reason either does not define it or does not define it at all

counting by diameter is not very clear. You want to calculate how many granules have a specific diameter? or what exactly is your goal? In your code, I only see stuff about detecting contours and drawing them. It's worth to note some contours will include more than one granule if your image is not pre-processed, since the granules are not clearly separated from each other

Added code.
That's right, I want to count how many granules have a size of 4mm, 2mm, and so on.
But the task is still to isolate the majority of these granules, about 90%.

I guess Watershed would help you here, follow this tutorial. The fine-tuning of the parameters will eventually be a trial and error...

same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78316410/searching-for-granules-and-determining-their-diameter#comment138099712_78316410

practical solution: give them static charge so they repel each other, allow them to distribute across a dark background.

unfortunately, nothing much can be used, I scattered it, counted it from above and that's it
