Searching for granules and determining their diameter
The problem is to determine as many and more precisely granules as possible in order to sort them by diameter in the future

At the moment, I have tried the code to define circles, but it is not accurate enough and determines the diameter a lot
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(r'D:\Downloads\bezsveta.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

img = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)

kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
img = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

retval, threshold = cv2.threshold(img, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()


params.minThreshold = 30
params.maxThreshold = 255

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(9,9),3)

params.filterByCircularity = True
params.minCircularity = 0.2

params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 20

ver = (cv2.__version__).split('.')
if int(ver[0]) < 3 :
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector(params)
else :
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)


keypoints = detector.detect(threshold)


im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

# Show keypoints
cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
cv2.waitKey(0)

result


why? why do this visually? why not mechanically? what is the goal of determining this information? why was this approach chosen? what other approaches were considered?

This is done for double-checking, using the cv2 method.HoughCircles (defines, but I want to be even more precise). The task is to define the granules as accurately and as much as possible in order to build diagrams in the future

same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78303549/counting-of-white-granules-by-their-diameter#comment138099708_78303549

I did an iteration of the parameter, it seems to work, but maybe someone will have tips on how to optimize?
import cv2
import numpy as np


img = cv2.imread(r'D:\Downloads\bezsveta.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
original_img = cv2.imread(r'D:\Downloads\bezsveta.jpg')


img = cv2.equalizeHist(img)


img = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, 9, 75, 75)


img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)


kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
img = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)


params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
params.minThreshold = 5
params.maxThreshold = 255
params.filterByCircularity = True
params.minCircularity = 0.1 
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 50 


detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)


img_with_keypoints = cv2.cvtColor(original_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


detected_circles = []


for retval in range(80, 255):  

    _, threshold = cv2.threshold(img, retval, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    

    keypoints = detector.detect(threshold)
    

    filtered_keypoints = []
    for keypoint in keypoints:
        is_overlap = False
        for circle in detected_circles + filtered_keypoints:
            distance = np.sqrt((keypoint.pt[0] - circle.pt[0])**2 + (keypoint.pt[1] - circle.pt[1])**2)
            if distance < (circle.size * 0.5 + keypoint.size * 0.5):  # Проверяем перекрытие кругов
                is_overlap = True
                break
        if not is_overlap:
            filtered_keypoints.append(keypoint)
    

    detected_circles.extend(filtered_keypoints)
    

    img_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(img_with_keypoints, filtered_keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)


    cv2.imshow("Keypoints", img_with_keypoints)
    cv2.waitKey(1)  


print("How much:", len(detected_circles))


cv2.waitKey(0) 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()  

